conda ModuleNotFoundError although package is installed
I'm having a problem with company proxy so I'm installing packages offline.

I downloaded the package from anaconda repository, to activate my conda env and then install it as following:

conda install C:\Users\path\to\package\matplotlib-3.9.2-py39haa95532_1.tar.bz2


The problem is when I import package in my code, I get following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'


Any hints on how to solve this ?

Tried to specify channel like this:


conda install -c conda-forge C:\Users\path\to\package\matplotlib-3.9.2-py39haa95532_1.tar.bz2

